# How can I replace a css class content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-color, rgba

I have a code where there's a place full of squares and inside that there's a a colored square moving every second, this square has a CSS class for it's color so it's not really moving, just adds a new class to a `<span>` and removes it after a second.

I have a function where I want to change the color of the square which would work like that:
`changeColor({R:50,G:200,B:50,A:1})`

I've been trying to make it work but i have this problem:

- Since I have a function adding and removing the square color's class I can't change the CSS class name, it has to be the same or the application won't work.
- If I use `.css("background", "rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ")");` it adds the color in the current `<span>` forever.
- I can't manage to have `.attr()` working, maybe I'm not doing it correctly.

I've tried using `.css`, `.removeClass`, `.addClass`, and `.attr`

None worked, maybe I'm not using it correctly.

```
function changeColor(sqColor) {

    R = sqColor.R;
    G = sqColor.G;
    B = sqColor.B;
    A = sqColor.A;

    $($("#container .sq_bullet a.sq_current > span")[0]).css("background", "rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ")");

}
```

(It's a.sq_current cause the "span" is inside an "a")

Full code is too long to post, sorry, take it as a really lot of `<span>` with nothing inside, just css attributes.

So the objective is to change the CSS class:

```
#container .sq_bullet a.sq_current > span {
    background: rgba(255,106,0,1);
}
```

to whatever I put in the function, ex: `changeColor({R:50,G:200,B:50,A:0.8})`

Comment: Couldn't you use a CSS animation with keyframes instead of a JS animation ?

Comment: Are you sure that your selector is correct? And that your function is called?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "CSS class". That's a ruleset.

Comment: @Jake
The animation is not mine, it's a very long code I got from a different place and it's part of an even longer code which makes it very hard to change it without showing errors.

Comment: @TraaZ That's the problem when you copy code you do not understand fully. There are several way you could do this, either use if / else statements and remove the existing style before applying your own, use multiple css classes and toggle them, etc.

Comment: @Glubus yes, I tested it in the console and it works when I use .css() but it just adds the attribute to the current span, after a second that span stays lets say grey forever but the "moving" square (which is a function with addClass and removeClass every second that gives that CSS to the current span) stays the same color as always lets say orange.

Comment: @Jake I understand the code but it's very long cause this is just a small part of a web application that is fully animated and can't really change it, some things would stop working or it would just take me so much time it's not worth it.

In the web there's a place where some images are shown every second (take a slider as an example it's very similar), there's another place full of hidden spans, except one, every second this one not hidden changes (everytime an image moves) this is the colored span, and because of all these animations I can't use .css(), I need to replace the CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by writing an inline  element to the header and then dynamically appending the styles to it. You can then add/remove the class on the span and update the styles in the  element independently without having to write any inline styles to the span.

Here is an example (this could be refined a lot, I just reused my previous example and tweaked it to demonstrate what I mean):

```js
var element = $("#container .sq_bullet a.sq_current > span").eq(0);

function changeColor(sqColor) {
  R = sqColor.R;
  G = sqColor.G;
  B = sqColor.B;
  A = sqColor.A;
  
  if (!$('myStyles').length) {
    $('head').append('<style id="myStyles" type="text/css"></style>');
  }
  var newStyle = ".myClass { background: rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ");}";
  $('#myStyles').html(newStyle);
}

element.addClass('myClass');
changeColor({R:50,G:200,B:50,A:0.8});

setTimeout(function() {
  element.removeClass('myClass');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  element.addClass('myClass');
  changeColor({R:200,G:50,B:50,A:0.8});
}, 4000);
```

```css
.myClass {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="sq_bullet">
    <a class="sq_current">
      <span>Span</span>
      <span>Span</span>
      <span>Span</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note this example creates an inline style block with the .myClass background set to green. It then adds the class to the span, after two seconds it removes the class, then two seconds later it changes the background colour to red and adds the class again - all without writing any inline styles onto the span itself.

Comment: This `$("#container .sq_bullet a.sq_current > span").eq(0)` does work but it actually does the same as the line I had.


Problem is .css() adds the attribute to the span (or a), so when the colored square changes it keeps using the same color it had, that's why I need to replace the CSS code, if I change the CSS it will change the color everytime.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do - if you run the code snippet above, is that doing what you want, or do you need something else?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. You want to be able to add/remove a class on the span, but you also want to dynamically change some of the properties of that class _without_ writing the styles inline on the span (so that they don't persist when the class is removed). Does that sound right?

Comment: that's it, I wrote a comment above explaining the app if that helps

Comment: Thank you! This definitely works but since I have it already animated all I had to do was change 
```$($("#container .sq_bullet a.sq_current > span")[0]).css("background", "rgba(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + "," + A + ")");```
 for 
```$("body").append("<style>.sq_current > span {background: rgba("+ R+","+ G+ "," + B + "," + A+ ") !important;}</style>")``` and it's working perfectly! 

Creating a new style in the head or body was the key

Comment: That's great, glad I could help :)